# Why is the REST endpoint being accessed twice, and can the second access be eliminated?

Tags: rest, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

The code "works", in that it returns the expected information (a list of *DemoPOJO* objects). However, as demonstrated by the console output shown below, two calls are being made to the REST service at *localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO*. I have a feeling that the second call is a result of a lack of understanding of reactive programming, but I do not see where the second call is being made on this REST API, and would like to eliminate it as the redundancy is likely to be a performance issue when "something real" is deployed.

In the code provided, a call is made on localhost:8080/v3/DemoClient (implemented in *DemoClientHandler*), which then uses a WebClient object to access a corresponding REST service at localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO (implemented in *DemoPOJOHandler*).

(I have stripped the code down to only those statements associated with the REST endpoint /v3/DemoClient)

```
2019-09-26 12:30:23.389  INFO 4260 --- [           main] com.test.demo.DemoApplication            : Starting DemoApplication on M7730-LFR with PID 4260 (D:\sandbox\DemoReactive\build\classes\java\main started by LesR in D:\sandbox\DemoReactive)
2019-09-26 12:30:23.391  INFO 4260 --- [           main] com.test.demo.DemoApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-26 12:30:24.570  INFO 4260 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
2019-09-26 12:30:24.573  INFO 4260 --- [           main] com.test.demo.DemoApplication            : Started DemoApplication in 1.41 seconds (JVM running for 1.975)
2019-09-26 12:30:28.796  INFO 4260 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] m.n.d.accesslogger.ServiceRequestLogger  : 
    *****  Begin, Access Request Log
    Service request    -> GET @ http://localhost:8080/v3/DemoClient
    Service handled by -> com.test.demo.democlient.DemoClientHandler.getAll()
    *****  End, Access Request Log
2019-09-26 12:30:28.823  INFO 4260 --- [ctor-http-nio-8] m.n.d.accesslogger.ServiceRequestLogger  : 
    *****  Begin, Access Request Log
    Service request    -> GET @ http://localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO
    Service handled by -> com.test.demo.demopojo.DemoPOJOHandler.getAll()
    *****  End, Access Request Log
2019-09-26 12:30:28.911  INFO 4260 --- [ctor-http-nio-9] m.n.d.accesslogger.ServiceRequestLogger  : 
    *****  Begin, Access Request Log
    Service request    -> GET @ http://localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO
    Service handled by -> com.test.demo.demopojo.DemoPOJOHandler.getAll()
    *****  End, Access Request Log
```

"Second-level" handler, access "first-level" REST API via WebClient (*DemoClient*)

```
@Component
public class DemoClientHandler {

    public static final String PATH_VAR_ID = "id";

    @Autowired
    ServiceRequestLogger svcRequestLogger;

    @Autowired
    DemoClient demoClient;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getAll(ServerRequest request) {
        Flux<DemoPOJO> fluxDemoPOJO = demoClient.getAll();

        svcRequestLogger.logServiceRequest(this.getClass(), "getAll()", request);

        return fluxDemoPOJO.hasElements().flatMap(hasElement -> {
            return hasElement ? ServerResponse.ok()
                                              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                              .body(fluxDemoPOJO, DemoPOJO.class)
                              : ServerResponse.noContent().build();
        });
    }
}
```

Uses *WebClient* to access "first-level" REST API...

```
@Component
public class DemoClient {

    private final WebClient client;

    public DemoClient() {
        client = WebClient.create();
    }

    public Flux<DemoPOJO> getAll() {
        return client.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO")
                           .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                           .exchange()
                           .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(DemoPOJO.class));
    }
)
```

"First-level" handler...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceRequestLogger svcRequestLogger;

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJOService service;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getAll(ServerRequest request) {
        Flux<DemoPOJO> fluxDemoPOJO = service.getAll();

        svcRequestLogger.logServiceRequest(this.getClass(), "getAll()", request);

        return fluxDemoPOJO.hasElements().flatMap(hasElement -> {
            return hasElement ? ServerResponse.ok()
                                              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                              .body(fluxDemoPOJO, DemoPOJO.class)
                              : ServerResponse.noContent().build();
        });
    }
}
```

Router for second-level (*WebClient*) REST API...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoClientRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> clientRoutes(DemoClientHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/v3"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/DemoClient"), requestHandler::getAll)));
    }
}
```

Router for first-level REST API...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoPOJORouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> demoPOJORoute(DemoPOJOHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/v2"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/DemoPOJO"), requestHandler::getAll)));
    }
}
```

Following code is added for completeness of the example, but I doubt is involved in the behavior I want to isolate-and-remove.

Service layer, supports DemoPOJO operations...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOService {

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJORepo demoPOJORepo;

    public Flux<DemoPOJO> getAll() {
        return Flux.fromArray(demoPOJORepo.getAll());
    }
}
```

Simple mock-up of POJO/data to support exploration...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJORepo {

    private static final int NUM_OBJS = 5;

    private static DemoPOJORepo demoRepo = null;

    private Map<Integer, DemoPOJO> demoPOJOMap;

    private DemoPOJORepo() {
        initMap();
    }

    public static DemoPOJORepo getInstance() {
        if (demoRepo == null) {
            demoRepo = new DemoPOJORepo();
        }
        return demoRepo;
    }

    public DemoPOJO[] getAll() {
        return demoPOJOMap.values().toArray(new DemoPOJO[demoPOJOMap.size()]);
    }

    private void initMap() {
        demoPOJOMap = new TreeMap<Integer, DemoPOJO>();

        for (int ndx = 1; ndx < (NUM_OBJS + 1); ndx++) {
            demoPOJOMap.put(ndx, new DemoPOJO(ndx, "foo_" + ndx, ndx + 100));
        }
    }
}
```

Logs (*SLF4J*/(Logback*) client access of REST services to application's log...

```
@Component
public class ServiceRequestLogger {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void logServiceRequest(Class serviceHandler, String serviceMethod, ServerRequest request) {
        logger.info(buildLogMessage(serviceHandler, serviceMethod, request));
    }

    private String buildLogMessage(Class serviceHandler, String serviceMethod, ServerRequest request) {
        StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder();

        /* <housekeeping code to build message to log */
        return logMessage.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you really sure it is making two requests, i dont trust your logging, run both applications in web debug and log on both sides

Comment: It may be "ugly" (and might be contributing to the issue), but *DemoClient* and *DemoPOJO* are both running on the same Netty server (and port) under a single *DemoApplication*. However, I have checked about there is (a) only a single call from *DemoClient* on *http://localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO*, (b) only a single place in the code where "access logging" is invoked for *DemoPOJOHandler.getAll()*, and (c) the two "access log entries" are made (including all debug-level logging on method entry points). In short, only one service invocation is logged, but the service runs twice.

Answer (score 0):

Probably violating some rule, but I've tried rephrasing the question and tightening up the code example at [Why is the handler for a REST endpoint being accessed twice, when accessed from a WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277541/why-is-the-handler-for-a-rest-endpoint-being-accessed-twice-when-accessed-from).

For the mods, I'm trying to avoid excessive editing of the original question, which can make comments appear non-topical.